# Alternative to Cookie Session for different applications within same domain

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies

I have 2 different ASP.NET applications on the same domain, different app pools on IIS. Application 1 opens Application 2 using `window.open(url)`. At this stage the cookie is shared among both applications. 
Application 2 runs the following code after login:

```
Context.Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value = string.Empty;
Context.Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-20);
```

The purpose of this code is to prevent Session Fixation vulnerability whereby an attacker could steal the session id pre-login, and use it post-login to authenticate themselves as a legitimate user.

However, this also changes the session id on Application 1, effectively login the user out of the application.
How can I prevent this from happening? and what other approaches could I follow?

Comment: You could set the valid path for the cookie. Not sure how to do it with asp.net though

Answer (score 0):

You could try use JSON web tokens instead

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/jwt-authentication-microservices-net/

https://jwt.io/